# send_file with X-Accel-Redirect won't return full file content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm doing `send_file` with Nginx using `X-Accel-Redirect` in a pretty straightforward way, but browsers won't download the full content. It's always cut off in the middle and the rest is truncated, like at 40KB for a 4MB file.

Rails 4.2.1 / Nginx 1.6.2

What is interrupting the file download?

production.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX
```

download_controller.rb

```
class DownloadController
  def download
    send_file '/full/path/to/file.csv'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add this info missing from your question: nginx server config file, nginx logs while trying to use this download endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of things for you to try:

1. Disable proxy buffering for that request by adding:

   ```
   response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
   ```

   To your download action like so:

   ```
   def download
     response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"
     send_file '/full/path/to/file.csv'
   end
   ```
2. Disable sendfile in the Nginx configuration

   This directive is known to cause trouble in virtual environments according to this article:
   http://www.conroyp.com/2013/04/25/css-javascript-truncated-by-nginx-sendfile/

While I am not sure if this will impact performance in a way that matters to you, trying these could be worth a shot and reveal more information that might help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having `client_max_body_size` in your ngnix conf file ?

> **From [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size):**
>   This is used to sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in the `Content-Length` request header field.
>    If the size in a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size

You can set in your conf file.

```
 server {
 ...
 client_max_body_size 4G;
 }
```

or

```
  location / {
  ...
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  }
```

Comment: I believe this is for file _uploads_ to the server. The question is about the nginx server truncating a file download.